# share a screen via ethernet and RPi

Tags: chromecast

I'd like to share/clone my laptops screen on a big screen via ethernet/wifi and a RPi.
The big screen would be connected to the RPi via HDMI , while all other devices connect to the RPi via ethernet/wifi and can then share their screen.

I found a relevant project but it seems to be dead:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=12100

Is there already a solution out to do so? Preferably without any client software installed on the devices.

Comment: Interesting idea and I think some aspects are possible - you could run a vnc SERVER on your laptop and a vnc CLIENT on the RPi (`tightvnc` seems to be one candidate) but I am not sure whether you would operate the laptop from it's own keyboard/mouse or you would have to work remotely from the RPi - perhaps *both* are achievable but I'd suspect the "driving from the RPi" is more likely to be doable - which is the opposite to what you want.

Comment: I think the easiest, cheapest way to do this at the moment is with a Chromecast. That said, this shouldn't be too difficult using ffmpeg, gstreamer or VLC, but you'll probably want to set up some scripts and shortcuts. The command lines can get a little hefty. That implementation's dependent on the OS of your laptop - what are you running?

Comment: In the ideal case I'd like to realize this without installing anything on my laptop and could be used by anyone who joins the network, windows 7, OSX and Linux machines alike. Do you think this is even possible?

Comment: It's going to be difficult to achieve the kind of minimal interaction you really want when you're screen casting like this. It should be easier than hooking up cables. Even using vnc you're going to have to set the session up on the casting machine, then log into that from the pi. Not ideal! I think the best I can come up with is VLC, which is common enough that it *might* already be on your sending machines.